# How to Browse ResultSet in thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to display attributes using thymeleaf from a ResultSet.

for exemple:
I want to show in my views the function's result using thymeleaf.

```
public ResultSet getIntervenantById(String nomTable, String id,String nomcle) {

        try {
            st = connection.prepareStatement("select * from ? where ? = ?");
            st.setString(1, nomTable);
            st.setString(2, nomcle);
            st.setString(3, id);
            rs = st.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rs ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html especially http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#model-attributes for your question. You really should start out by learning the basics - Thymeleaf's website provides some good stuff: http://www.thymeleaf.org/documentation.html

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to handle this problem.  Here is a quick and dirty one just to display the results.  You can create a `List` and add it to your `model`.

**Service (MyService):**

```
public static List createList(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {

    ResultSetMetaData metadata = resultSet.getMetaData();
    int numberOfColumns = metadata.getColumnCount();

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(numberOfColumns);
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= numberOfColumns) {
            list.add(resultSet.getString(i++));
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

**Controller**:

```
@GetMapping("/myPage")
public String getList(Model model) {
   ResultSet resultSet = ...; //however you call this     
   model.addAttribute("items", MyService.createList(resultSet); //try block hidden for brevity
   return "myPage";
}
```

**HTML (myPage.html):**

```
<div th:each="item : ${items}">
    <span th:text="${item}">No item</span>
</div>
```

---

Another (arguably cleaner) way to do this is to use implement a [`RowMapper`](http://www.dineshonjava.com/2012/12/implementing-rowmapper-chapter-34.html).  I am excerpting some of the code as an example:

```
public class EmployeeMapper implements RowMapper {  
   public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {  
      Employee employee = new Employee();  
      employee.setEmpid(rs.getInt("empid"));  
      employee.setName(rs.getString("name"));  
      employee.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));  
      employee.setSalary(rs.getLong("salary"));  
      return employee;  
   }  
}
```

Then you may have:

```
public Employee getEmployee(Integer empid) {
   String SQL = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE empid = ?";
   Employee employee = (Employee) jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(SQL, new Object[]{empid}, new EmployeeMapper());
    return employee;
}
```

And you can add these beans to the model and iterate as above.  There is also the `BeanPropertyRowMapper` for a quick implementation of the `RowMapper` from Spring.

Though instead of going this route with `ResultSet`s, you may be better off with a JPA implementation and just returning `List` objects.  It's some more dependencies, but less code for you to maintain in the end.