# Thymeleaf - while true loop

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I'd like to add a `while(boolean)` on a HTML using Thymeleaf. Is this possible?

To be more specific, I want to do something similar to the `ResultSet.next` function on my HTML.

I've tried to use `th:block th:while="${feature.next()}"` but it looks like th:while doesn't exist.

```
        <tbody>
            <tr th:block th:while="${feature.next()}">
                <td th:block th:each="fu : ${feature.getFieldUsages()}"><span th:text="${fu.field.toText()}"></span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

I was expecting to loop `${feature.next()}` while returning true.

Best regards,
Jonathan

Comment: The following post explains how to browse a ResultSet in Thymeleaf: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44269680/how-to-browse-resultset-in-thymeleaf